# Basic Options Understanding

Tags: options, call-options, put-options

Two general questions:

1) If "A" creates a put option, "B" buys it, then resells it to "C". If "C" exercises the option, who gets assigned: "A" or "B"?

2) If I buy a call option, it has the same effect as selling a put option right?

Answer (score 2):

If you buy something and then you sell it, you no longer own anything.  So if B buys it and sells it, he's out of the equation.  A and C are the counter parties.

Buying a call does not have the same effect as selling a put.

[image]

[image]